# Concatenar Strings em Java Loops - StringBuilder ou '+'?

Tags: java, string, desempenho, loop, concatenação-de-string

Java permite que possamos concatenar Strings em Java utilizando apenas o operador '+'

```
String str = "a" + "b" + "c";
```

É uma maneira simples de se fazer o trabalho, e bem menos verbosa do que com StringBuilder.

Mas em casos de Loops como o abaixo, qual abordagem é a mais performática?

'+' ou StringBuilder?

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String s = "a";

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            s += "a";
        }

        System.out.println("Total time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime));
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**De acordo com a JSL - Java Specification Language**

[15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

O operador '+' oferece a facilidade de ser um único caracter para concatenar Strings, e seu uso é enconrajado. Na verdade ao ser compilado o compilador troca por um **StringBuilder**

Embora este seja um recurso valioso, não deve ser usado em loops como o da pergunta acima.

**Por que?**

Um novo StringBuilder será criado a cada iteração (com o valor inicial de str) e no fim de cada iteração, haverá concatenação com a String inicial (na verdade StringBuilder com valor inicial de str).
Então, você devemos criar StringBuilder nós mesmos somente quando estivermos concatenando Strings em loops.

Veja como deve ficar o código, compare a performance de ambos, é chocante, quão mais rápido o programa fica:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String s = "a";
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            strBuilder.append("a");
        }

        System.out.println("Total time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime));
    }
```

Fonte: 
http://jknowledgecenter.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/always-use-stringbuilder-while.html

Comment: +1 E pra quem se interessar, "descompilei" os códigos acima ([ligeiramente modificados](http://pastebin.com/Ris7Bi0s)) e verifiquei que - [nos bytecodes](http://pastebin.com/Aq5uEKtW) (compilado no Ubuntu - `javac 1.7.0_79`) - de fato um novo `StringBuilder` é criado a cada iteração do loop.

Comment: Sim, é incrivel o compilador deveria inferir um StringBuilder único.

Comment: Usando StringBuilder: Total time: 5.106.995 (nano seconds) (5 milhões) Usando o '+': Total time: 4.192.903.645 (nano seconds) (4 BILHÕES) Diferença enorme...

Comment: Muito bom. Vinvendo e apre"e"ndendo.

Comment: Uma curiosidade: O sonarQube gera uma issue em concatenações dentro de loops com `+` "In each iteration, the String is converted to a StringBuffer/StringBuilder, appended to, and converted back to a String. This can lead to a cost quadratic in the number of iterations, as the growing string is recopied in each iteration. Better performance can be obtained by using a StringBuffer (or StringBuilder in Java 1.5) explicitly."