# Classe robot com Variável

Tags: java

Eu estou com um código e preciso escrever o valor de uma variável atraves da classe robot, por exemplo:

```
int camera=2
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_M);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
```

Eu estou me importando com o valor que vem ao lado da palavra, quero que o valor da variável seja escrito, podendo ser variado ao decorrer do código.

Comment: Não é mais facil monitorar a palavra inteira de uma vez ao inves de letra por letra? Se eu escrever "cdamehera" seu algoritmo vai contar como camera tambem.

Comment: Não tem muita importância o restante do código, o que eu preciso mesmo é aprender como pegar a variável e digitar o valor dela em outro lugar.

Comment: Pois é, mas como não está muito claro o que esse código deveria fazer, e como não tem como executar, fica dificil sugerir algo.

Comment: Ele tem que fazer exatamente o que você está vendo, escrever "camera1", depois ele vai somar 1 na variável e vai ter que escrever "camera2", quantas vezes forem necessarias.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getExtendedKeyCodeForChar-int-):

```
final String string = "camera";

for(char character : string.toCharArray()){
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(character));
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(character));
}
```

Caso precise concatenar o valor "camera" com um número (ou outra string), há [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/4808) que já aborda o assunto.

```
final int MAX = 5;
final Robot robot = new Robot();

for(int i = 1; i <= MAX; i++){
   final String string = "camera" + i;
   for(char character : string.toCharArray()){
      robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(character));
      robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.getExtendedKeyCodeForChar(character));
   }
   // só para pular linha no output, não são necessárias as duas linhas abaixo.
   robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

**output:**

```
camera1
camera2
camera3
camera4
camera5
```

Comment: Não entendi o que como fazer isso

Comment: Isto vai escrever o conteúdo da variável `string` letra por letra. Não é essa a sua dúvida?

Comment: Talvez ajude, mas não era exatamente isso, eu estou me importando com o valor que vem ao lado da palavra, quero que o valor da variável seja escrito, podendo ser variado ao decorrer do código.

Comment: Isso deveria estar descrito na sua pergunta, se há mais detalhes de implementação, edite a pergunta e explique-os. No mais: [como concatenar strings](https://pt.staackoverflow.com/q/71517/4808).

Comment: Na verdade foi o que quis dizer com "escrever o valor da variável" e "aumentando a variável cada vez que a palavra for escrita", mas estou editando de qualquer forma.

Comment: +1 Muito bom vc mostrar esse método! Só uma dúvida, não é necessário chamar `keyRelease()` após o `keyPress()`? Quanto a dúvida do @LucasMoraesdeSouza eu acho que ele quer que o robô escreva "camera1", depois "camera2", depois "camera3" ... até "cameraN" (onde N é um número definido por ele, e "camera" é uma String _prefixo_ também definida por ele). É isso mesmo Lucas?

Comment: @Douglas não sei, não costumo utilizar essa classe. Mas faz sentido seu questionamento, até encontrei [uma pergunta no stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7315803/4056678) sobre o assunto. Talvez tenha efeito colateral no caso de combinações do tipo "ctrl + c", onde "C" deve ser pressionado com o ctrl também pressionado. Mas editei a pergunta, melhor garantir. O restante da dúvida é basicamente concatenar strings, que já há "n" perguntas sobre o assunto por aqui.

Comment: @Renan, eu não entendo como a concatenação de string pode me ajudar com isso, se você sabe, te peço, por favor, uma explicação.

Comment: @Douglas sim, é exatamente isso.

Comment: @LucasMoraesdeSouza resposta editada.