# Como fazer um triângulo de asteriscos em java

Tags: java, for

Pretendo obter o seguinte output:

n:4

+

++

+++

++++

Ou seja,insiro um "n" e vou obter uma espécie de triângulo em que a base corresponde a um número de asteriscos que é pedido por input.Fiz o seguinte código mas este apenas acerta no número de linhas e não de elementos por linha:

```
System .out . println("Indique um número inteiro positivo:");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int triangulos = 0;
    int i ;
    for(i=0; triangulos < n ; triangulos++)
    {
        System.out.println("n:" + n);
        System.out.println("*");
    }
```

Comment: O triangulo está pela metade. Não precisa ser um triangulo completo?

Comment: Faltou outro `for` para gerar os asteriscos

Comment: Seus asteriscos tem umas pernas faltando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println("Indique um número inteiro positivo:");
int n = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("n: " + n);
for(int i = 0; i <= n ; i++) {
    String out = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        out.concat("*");
    }
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

Na primeira iteração percorremos os `n`

Na segunda adicionamos `"*"` `i` vezes conforme iteramos o `n`

Comment: Não existe append na classe String.

Comment: Desculpa, erro meu, append() seria um método da classe StringBuilder, o equivalente da String é o método concat()

Comment: Sim de fato no Java 7 não existe. Como não sei qual a versão q ele está usando. Admito q seja a 8.

Comment: Basta usar `+`(`out+="*"`) que torna compativel com qualquer versão. Ou adaptar direto para Stringbuilder

Comment: Sim de fato, porém quando usamos o operador + na compilação há a troca automática por StringBuilder. Em um laço se usarmos esse operador vamos estar perdendo performance.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71517/concatenar-strings-em-java-loops-stringbuilder-ou

Comment: Não há diferença de performances que sejam signifcativas,  pra um código tão simples que seja necessário utilizar stringbuilder. Chega a ser um despercidio de recursos até.

Comment: Na realidade com o operador + a cada iteração um novo objeto StringBuilder será criado e concatenado `a String inicial. Como visto em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909369/using-stringbuilder-with-for-loop

Comment: Outro link interessante: http://www.pellegrino.link/2015/08/22/string-concatenation-with-java-8.html