# Como mostrar valores de uma Matriz em uma única mensagem?

Tags: java, array, matriz

```
package Algoritmos;

import javax.swing.*;

public class testinho {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] numero_conta = new int[3][3];
        numero_conta[0][0] = 111;
        numero_conta[0][1] = 222;
        numero_conta[0][2] = 333;
        numero_conta[1][0] = 444;
        numero_conta[1][1] = 555;
        numero_conta[1][2] = 666;
        numero_conta[2][0] = 777;
        numero_conta[2][1] = 888;
        numero_conta[2][2] = 999;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numero_conta);
    }
}
```

Gostaria de saber como faço para mostrar todos os valores de minha matriz sem que eu precise usar um `for` para mostrar um valor por vez, e nem que eu precise dizer exatamente a posição do valor (ex: `numero_conta[1][0]`), quero que seja mostrado de uma vez tudo que tem na matriz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método `deepToString` de `Arrays`. Este método transforma arrays multidimensionais em strings.

**Exemplo:**

```
String numeroConta = Arrays.deepToString(numero_conta);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, numeroConta);
```

Answer (score 1):

Por que você não quer usar um `for`? *Loops* são estruturas básicas da linguagem, e um dos seus usos é justamente percorrer uma lista ou array, para fazer algo com seus elementos.

Você até pode usar o método [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString-java.lang.Object:A-), como sugerido na [resposta do @renanzin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/410837/112052), mas deve se lembrar que este método também itera pelo array (ou seja, você estará usando `for` indiretamente - só porque você não escreveu um *loop*, não quer dizer que não há algum sendo usado). Outro detalhe é que neste caso você não tem controle sobre o formato de saída, e vai ter que aceitar o que o método retorna, que no caso é essa `String`:

```
[[111, 222, 333], [444, 555, 666], [777, 888, 999]]
```

Se você quiser mudar o formato em que os dados são retornados, aí não tem jeito, tem que usar um *loop* e montar a string do jeito que você precisa. Exemplo:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int[] linha : numero_conta) {
    for (int elemento : linha) {
        sb.append(elemento).append(' ');
    }
    sb.append('\n');
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());
```

Eu uso um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) para ir montando a `String`, pois ele [é mais eficiente para fazer concatenações de *strings* em um *loop*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052). Usei também a sintaxe de *foreach*, assim não precisa dos índices (pois neste caso só estou interessado nos elementos).

No caso, usei um espaço para separar os elementos, e adicionei uma quebra de linha (`\n`) para separar as linhas da matriz (mas você pode mudar o formato da maneira que achar melhor). A saída é:

```
111 222 333 
444 555 666 
777 888 999
```

O detalhe é que este código adiciona um espaço no final de cada linha (após o último elemento), além de uma quebra de linha após a última linha. No `JOptionPane` talvez não dê para perceber isso, mas se quiser ser mais detalhista e não colocar esses espaços e esta linha a mais, aí você precisa dos índices para saber quando colocá-los ou não:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < numero_conta.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numero_conta[i].length; j++) {
        sb.append(numero_conta[i][j]);
        if (j != numero_conta[i].length - 1) // não é o último elemento da linha
            sb.append(' ');
    }
    if (i != numero_conta.length - 1) // não é a última linha
        sb.append('\n');
}
```

Agora o espaço não é adicionado no final da linha, e a quebra de linha não é adicionada depois da última linha.

Comment: Mas e se eu tivesse 3 matrizes e precisasse mostrar todos os valores com uma ordem, a ordem seria (nome_correntista, numero_conta, saldo)? O motivo de eu não poder usar um for é que eu preciso mostrar todos os valores de apenas uma vez.

Comment: @Gatenho Aí vc já está mudando a pergunta, pois não tem nada disso no seu código. Mas basicamente vc faz um loop nessas matrizes e vai concatenando as strings com o StringBuilder da forma que precisar. Se for o caso, [faça outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) dando todos os detalhes (como estão essas matrizes, como quer a saída, etc)

Comment: Eu preciso esperar mais 3 dias antes de efetuar outra pergunta, mas tudo bem vou esperar para poder perguntar, obrigado