# Trocar os primeiros caracteres de uma String por outro

Tags: java, string

Estou criando um '*banco falso*' e queria fazer um método em que mostra parcialmente a senha.

Criei um array chamado `senha2` e os 4 primeiros caracteres são mostrados como `*`, por exemplo:

```
senha : ****restoDaSenha
```

Mas se eu faço:

```
String senha3 = senha.charAt(4);

String[] senha2 = { "*", "*", "*", "*", this.senha3};
```

Ele não dá erro mas acontece isso na output:

> Senha : [Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742

Qual o problema no código existente? É um problema de implementação, aplicação da linguagem?

Meu código:

```
package bancofake;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Banco {
    String nome; // Dono -> fisico ou juridico
    String senha; // Senha -> Senha da conta para nenhum ladrão louco roubar dinheiro
    double saldo;
    int id; // Id da conta

    String[] senha2 = { "*", "*", "*", "*"};

    int tentativa;

      public void criarSenha() {

          String senhacriada = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual a senha ?"));

            if(senhacriada.length() >= 8) { 
                System.out.println("Senha criada");
                this.senha = senhacriada;
            }else{
                System.err.println("A senha deve ter no minimo 8 caracteres !"); 
                if(tentativa < 2) {
                    this.tentativa += 1;
                    this.criarSenha();
                }
            }
      }



    public void depositar(double quantidade) {

        int idrecebeu = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual o ID da conta ?"));

        if (idrecebeu == this.id) {
            if (quantidade >= 0) {
                this.saldo += quantidade;
                System.out.println("Depositado R$" + quantidade + " com Sucesso !");
                System.out.println("==| Informação |==");
                System.out.println("Id da Conta : " + this.id);
                System.out.println("Nome do Dono(fisico ou juridico) : ");
                System.out.println(this.nome);
                System.out.println("Saldo : R$" + this.saldo);
            } else if (quantidade <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Você não pode depositar R$" + quantidade + " !");
                System.out.println("Pois a quantidade é igual ou menor que 0 !");
            } else {
                System.err.println("A quantidade não é Depositavel !");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("O ID está incorreto e/ou não existe !");
        }
    }

    public void retirar(double quantidade) {

        int idrecebido = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual o ID da conta ?"));
        String senharecebida = (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qual a senha ?"));

        if (idrecebido == this.id && senharecebida == this.senha) {
            if (saldo != 0) {
                if (quantidade >= 0) {
                    this.saldo -= quantidade;
                    System.out.println("Retirado R$" + quantidade + " com Sucesso !");
                    System.out.println("==| Informação |==");
                    System.out.println("Id da Conta : " + this.id);
                    System.out.println("Nome do Dono(fisico ou juridico) : ");
                    System.out.println(this.nome);
                    System.out.println("Saldo : R$" + this.saldo);
                } else if (quantidade <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Você não pode retirar R$" + quantidade + " !");
                    System.out.println("Pois a quantidade é igual ou menor que 0 !");
                } else {
                    System.err.println("A quantidade não é Retiravel !");
                }
            } else if (saldo <= 0) {
                System.out.println("A quantidade não é permitida !");
                System.out.println("Saldo : " + this.saldo);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("O ID ou a Senha está Incorreto !");
        }
    }

    public void verificarSaldo() {
        System.out.println("Saldo : " + this.saldo);
        System.out.println("Id da conta : " + this.id);
        System.out.println("Dono da conta : " + this.nome);
        System.out.println("Senha : " + this.senha);
    }

    public void verificarsenha() {
        System.out.println("Senha : "+this.senha);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

Por exemplo, se a senha for "abcdefgh", quero que a saída seja:

```
****efgh
```

Comment: Edite a pergunta e inclua todo o código envolvido, só isso que você postou só da pra dizer que você está imprimindo o endereço de memória variável

Comment: O código eu coloquei tudo , Ele tá meio ruim pois estou aprendendo Java nesse Mês .

Comment: Como vc esta imprimindo na tela?

Comment: ```System.out.prinln("Senha : "+senha_parcialmente);```

Comment: se senha = "12345678" então Senha_parcialmente = "****5678" ou "1234****"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em Java, quando você imprime um array diretamente (`System.out.println(array)`), os elementos deste não são mostrados. Em vez disso, é mostrada a informação do tipo do array e seu hashcode, conforme explicado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403).

Para o caso específico de um array de `String`, uma alternativa para mostrar o conteúdo do array como uma única `String` é usar o [método `String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) (disponível a partir do Java 8):

```
String[] senhaParcial = { "*", "*", "*", "*", "resto"};
System.out.println(String.join("", senhaParcial)); // ****resto
```

Ou usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
String[] senhaParcial = { "*", "*", "*", "*", "resto"};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String s: senhaParcial) {
    sb.append(s);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString()); // ****resto
```

Para fazer várias concatenações em um *loop*, o `StringBuilder` [é mais eficiente do que concatenar strings diretamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052) (que foi o código sugerido [na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/432143/112052)).

---

## Mas para que esse array afinal?

Se você só quer substituir os 4 primeiros caracteres de uma `String` por `*`, **não precisa criar esse array**. Basta criar outra `String`, substituindo esses caracteres:

```
// método que troca os primeiros caracteres da senha
public String escondeSenha(String senha, char secret, int qtd) {
    char[] caracteres = senha.toCharArray();
    // pega o menor número entre o tamanho do array e a quantidade informada
    int tamanho = Math.min(caracteres.length, qtd);
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        caracteres[i] = secret;
    }
    return new String(caracteres); // ****efgh
}

String senha = "abcdefgh";
//trocar os 4 primeiros caracteres por *
System.out.println(escondeSenha(senha, '*', 4)); // ****efgh
```

Tomei o cuidado de verificar se a quantidade de caracteres a ser substituída não é maior que o tamanho da string.

Fazendo desta forma, você não precisa criar um array à toa, e ainda deixa o código mais flexível, podendo mudar a quantidade e o caractere usado.

---

Mas se a ideia é **somente** imprimir, nem precisa gerar outra `String`:

```
String senha = "abcdefgh";
int qtd = 4;
int tamanho = Math.min(qtd, senha.length());
for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) { // imprime várias vezes o "*"
    System.out.print('*'); // print não pula a linha
}
// imprime o resto da String
if (tamanho < senha.length())
    System.out.println(senha.substring(qtd));
```

Primeiro eu imprimo várias vezes o `*` (usando [`print`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print-char:A-) em vez de [`println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println-java.lang.String-), para não pular a linha). Depois eu vejo se ainda faltam caracteres a serem impressos, e uso o método [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) para pegar o restante da `String` (também tomando o cuidado de verificar se o tamanho indicado não ultrapassa o tamanho da `String`).

Answer (score 1):

isso acontece por que você criou um vetor String[] e quando você imprimi a variável que esta linkada no vetor ele vai te dar o endereço dele na memória,

para resolver esse problema você pode tentar isso.

```
    String[] senha = { "*", "*", "*", "resto"};
    String senhafinal = "";


    for(String caracter : senha) {

     senhafinal = senhafinal.concat(caracter);
    }

    System.out.println(senhafinal);
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado !