# Qual a melhor forma de converter um int array em String no Java?

Tags: java

Qual o melhor método de se converter **{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}** pra **"12345"** ?

Exemplo:

```java
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
array.toString(); // Existe alguma função que faça isso?
```

Eu sei que dá pra fazer com um for loop mas talvez tenha opções melhores.

```java
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
String s = ""; // Sei que tem StringBuilder também
for (int i : array) {
    s += i;
}
```

Comment: Já tentou `Arrays.toString(array)` do `java.util.Arrays` ?

Comment: Em um loop, `StringBuilder` é melhor que concatenar strings com `+`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052

Comment: @LuizAugusto Se não me engano, `Arrays.toString` coloca vírgula entre os elementos, mas a pergunta pede para juntar os números, sem nenhum separador

Comment: @hkotsubo sim sim, fiz um teste aqui e verifiquei isto, que não iria servir para tal propósito.

Comment: E a [resposta abaixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/444159/112052) é uma opção válida, mas não sei se é "o melhor jeito" (partindo do pressuposto que performance é um critério pra considerar "melhor", então não é, pois [streams são mais lentas que um loop simples](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052)). Mas quem gosta de uma "pegada mais funcional", com certeza achará melhor :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que a melhor forma tanto em legibilidade quanto eficiência é usar `StringBuilder` mesmo, valeu pela ajuda aí gente.

```java
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i : array) sb.append(i);
```

Answer (score 5):

Eis um código que pode te ajudar:

```java
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        String resposta = IntStream.of(array).mapToObj(String::valueOf).reduce("", String::concat);
        System.out.println(resposta);
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no Ideone.**](https://ideone.com/XBY761)

A ideia dele é primeiro converter o array em um [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) e depois em um [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) de `String`s, usando o [`String.valueOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)) para converter `int` em `String`. Por fim, o [`reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)) concatena todas as `String`s resultantes (usando o [método `concat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) em uma só.

Apesar de que para ser sincero, provavelmente a solução usando um `for` e um `StringBuilder` será a que tem o melhor desempenho.

Comment: Testei teu código em um array de 100 mil unidades e ele foi mais de 100x mais lento que usando um StringBuilder
Pensei em uma forma interessante de fazer o que eu quero, o comentário do Luiz me fez ter essa ideia: `Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll("([\\[\\], ])", "");`
É umas 5x mais rápido que o seu e tem um código menor (mas continua sendo bem mais lento que com StringBuilder então vou continuar usando ele) mas achei interessante esse método pra pequenos arrays, anyway valeu pelo conhecimento amigo

Comment: @inosivel [Código menor não é necessariamente melhor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400495/112052), e usar `replace` é gambiarra (pode até "funcionar" pra esse caso específico, mas e se for um array de string e uma delas tiver um `[` no meio do texto, ele será indevidamente removido, entre outros casos que pode dar problema, como arrays de arrays, por exemplo). Usar streams ou um loop simples é melhor porque vc terá controle total do formato e não depende de detalhes de implementação de `toString` - veja mais em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu sei, vou continuar usando o `StringBuilder` por ser mais legível e rápido, só achei a solução criativa mesmo

Answer (score 2):

Se você estiver usando Java 8, pode usar stream:

```
    String str = Arrays.stream(intArray).mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .reduce((a, b) -> a.concat(b)).get();
```

Se precisar algum char pra concatenar vc pode usar o concat

```
    a.concat(",").concat(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Só para complementar as outras respostas, a partir do Java 8 é possível usar [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)). Mas como este método deve receber uma ou mais instâncias de [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/CharSequence.html) e `int`'s não são `CharSequence`'s, ainda temos que converter o array de `int` para um array de `String`:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
String s = String.join("", IntStream.of(array).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new));
System.out.println(s); // 12345
```

Se bem que neste caso, eu ainda prefiro a [solução que usa um *loop* e um `StringBuilder`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/444194/112052), que é [melhor que a concatenação com `+`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052) (e ambas, por sua vez, [são mais rápidas que *streams*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052)).

---

Outra opção (**que só funciona se os valores do array são todos números entre 0 e 9**) é construir um número com os dígitos do array e no final convertê-lo para `String`:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int n = 0;
for (int i : array) {
    n *= 10;
    n += i;
}
String result = String.format("%0" + array.length + "d", n); // 12345
```

Usei [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) para colocar os zeros à esquerda, caso os primeiros elementos do array sejam `0` (pois se eu só imprimir o número diretamente, ele é mostrado sem os zeros à esquerda). Eu também uso o tamanho do array (`array.length`) para que a quantidade de dígitos mostrada seja a mesma quantidade que tem no array (assim, um array como `{0, 0, 0, 1}` resulta na string `0001`).