# Como faço um programa para inverter uma senha ignorando os caracteres # e _?

Tags: java, stack

Tenho um exercício para fazer com esse tema mas não consigo inverter a segunda parte depois de um caractere especial.

Exemplo: `teste_baixo#123` seria trocado por `etset_oxiab#321`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PilhaInt pilha = new PilhaInt();

        pilha.init();

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        String senha = new String();
        String salva = new String();

        System.out.println("insira senha= ");
        senha = teclado.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < senha.length(); i++) {
            if (senha.charAt(i) != '_' && senha.charAt(i) != '#') {
                pilha.push(senha.charAt(i));
            }else{
                for (int j = i-1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    System.out.printf("%c",senha.charAt(j));
                }
                System.out.println(senha.charAt(i));
            }
            System.out.println(pilha.topo);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não colocou o código da classe `PilhaInt`, mas vamos assumir que ela está completa e possui um método `pop`, que desempilha o elemento do topo e o retorna, e que também possui um método para verificar se ela está vazia. Então a ideia do algoritmo é ir empilhando os caracteres até encontrar um `_` ou `#`.

No caso, eu empilho o `t`, depois o `e`, depois o `s`, etc... E ao encontrar o caractere `_`, a pilha estará assim:

```
e  <-- topo
t
s
e
t
```

Ao encontrar o `_`, basta desempilhar esses elementos e ir adicionando na nova senha, que eles já serão colocados em ordem inversa (já que o desempilhamento começa do elemento mais ao topo). Faça isso até que a pilha esteja vazia. Depois você adiciona o próprio `_` na nova senha e prossegue o *loop*.

Ficaria assim:

```
String senha = "teste_baixo#123";
String novaSenha = "";
for (int i = 0; i < senha.length(); i++) {
    char c = senha.charAt(i);
    if (c != '_' && c != '#') {
        pilha.push(c);
    } else { // é "_" ou "#", esvazia a pilha
        while (!pilha.isVazia()) {
            novaSenha += pilha.pop();
        }
        novaSenha += c; // adiciona o _ ou #
    }
}
// pode ter sobrado alguma coisa na pilha
while (!pilha.isVazia()) {
    novaSenha += pilha.pop();
}
System.out.println(novaSenha); // etset_oxiab#321
```

---

Eu usei concatenação de strings com `+`, mas você também poderia usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), pois [em *loops* ele é mais eficiente que usar `+`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052).

Também dá para eliminar a repetição do bloco `while` criando um método específico para aquele trecho:

```
private void esvaziaPilha(Pilha pilha, StringBuilder novaSenha) {
    while (!pilha.isVazia()) {
        novaSenha.append(pilha.pop());
    }
}

...
String senha = "teste_baixo#123";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < senha.length(); i++) {
    char c = senha.charAt(i);
    if (c != '_' && c != '#') {
        pilha.push(c);
    } else { // é _ ou #, esvazia a pilha
        esvaziaPilha(pilha, sb);
        sb.append(c); // adiciona o _ ou #
    }
}
esvaziaPilha(pilha, sb);
String novaSenha = sb.toString();
```

Comment: magnífico cara, explicação completa e clara, muito obrigado!!