# Como exibir as iniciais do nome do usuários sem os seus conectores?

Tags: java, string

A partir de um nome informado pelo usuário, exibir suas inicias mas sem os seus conectores.

Por exemplo: josé da silva -> JS

Consegui gerar o código para imprimir as iniciais mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que o programa não imprima os conectores.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String nome;        
    
    System.out.println("Digite o seu nome: ");
    nome = in.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    
    System.out.println("A inicias do seu nome: ");
    System.out.print(nome.charAt(0));
    
    for(int i=0; i<nome.length(); i++) {            
        if(nome.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            System.out.print(nome.charAt(i + 1));
        }                   
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu retornaria todas as letras maiúsculas, mas antes eu faria um função que separar usando o caractere espaço e depois faria verificaria se a letra inicial é maiúscula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deu como exemplo "josé da silva", então estou assumindo que a string não necessariamente vai ter letras maiúsculas e minúsculas corretamente (como um nome normalmente teria, por exemplo: "José da Silva"). Ou seja, entendo que podemos ter casos como "josé DA silVA", "JOSé dA sILVa", etc.

O problema de fazer um *loop* caractere a caractere é que você terá que ir montando manualmente as substrings contendo cada parte do nome. Em vez disso, você pode usar [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) para separar a string por espaços.

Depois, para cada parte, basta ver se ela é um dos conectores. Se não for, adiciona a inicial. Algo assim:

```
String nome = "josé da silva";
List<String> conectores = Arrays.asList("do", "da", "de"); // coloque aqui todos os conectores que precisar
StringBuilder iniciais = new StringBuilder();
for (String parte: nome.split(" ")) {
    if (! conectores.contains(parte.toLowerCase())) { // se não é um conector
        iniciais.append(Character.toUpperCase(parte.charAt(0)));
    }
}
System.out.println("Iniciais: " + iniciais.toString()); // JS
```

Primeiro o `split` separa a string por espaços, assim eu posso verificar cada parte do nome separadamente.

Criei uma lista de conectores (todos em letras minúsculas), e para cada parte do nome eu verifico se ele é um conector. Se não for, eu adiciono a primeira letra (transformada em maiúscula) no [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Você até poderia concatenar as strings no `for`, mas [em um *loop*, usar `StringBuilder` é mais eficiente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052).

---

Não ficou claro se sempre tem exatamente um único espaço separando cada um dos nomes. Se tiver mais de um espaço entre eles, basta trocar para `nome.split(" +")` - o parâmetro do `split` é uma expressão regular (regex) e no caso o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências" (ou seja, `" +"` significa "um ou mais espaços"). Você também poderia usar `nome.split("\\s+")`, só que o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s` também considera outros caracteres além do espaço, como <kbd>TAB</kbd> e quebras de linha ([veja mais detalhes aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)).

---

Outra alternativa (desnecessariamente complicada, fica aqui somente como "curiosidade") é fazer o `split` considerando os próprios conectores:

```
String nome = "josé   da silva   DOS  SANTos";
StringBuilder iniciais = new StringBuilder();
for (String parte : nome.split("(?i)\\s+(d[aeo]s?)\\s+")) {
    iniciais.append(Character.toUpperCase(parte.charAt(0)));
}
System.out.println("Iniciais: " + iniciais.toString()); // JSS
```

A [*flag inline*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(?i)` indica que a regex será *case insensitive* (não diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas). Depois temos um ou mais espaços, seguido de `d[aeo]s?`. A [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[aeo]` pega a letra "a", ou "e", ou "o" e o `s?` indica que a letra "s" é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) (fiz assim para aceitar "de", "do", "da", "dos", "das" e "des"). Portanto, essa regex pega todos esses conectores, contendo espaços antes e depois.

Assim, o retorno do `split` já excluirá os conectores (e também os espaços antes e depois deles), não precisando verificá-los dentro do *loop*.

Mas como já disse, eu acho desnecessariamente complicada, sendo mais simples manter uma lista com todos os conectores, como a primeira sugestão acima (pois conforme esta lista cresce, a regex ficará cada vez mais complexa).

Comment: Show mestre! Muito 'thanks'. Além de explicar de uma forma concisa e objetiva, apresentou ainda outras opções agregando muito valor ao meu conhecimento.

Answer (score 0):

Fala amigão, você precisa checar de alguma forma se é um conector, fiz um exemplo mas tem outras maneiras de fazer, veja que no meu caso eu testo se a inicial começa em minúsculo:

```
    String nome = "Jose da Silva";
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String palavra : nome.split(" ")) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(palavra.charAt(0))) {
            builder.append(palavra.charAt(0));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Observe também que é recomendado usar `StringBuilder` pois se trata de apenas um objeto uma vez que `String` é uma classe imutável.