# Estou tentando abrir um arquivo com JFileChooser e ler com o BufferedReader porém só está lendo a ultima linha

Tags: java

aqui esta o código

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Layout extends JFrame {
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu arq = new JMenu("Arquivo");
    JMenuItem abrir = new JMenuItem("Abir");
    public Layout(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setLayout( new GridLayout(1,1));
        setJMenuBar(menu);
        add(ta);
        menu.add(arq);
        arq.add(abrir);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        abrir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "txt", "txt");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                   String caminho = chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath();
                      try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(caminho))){
                           String linha = br.readLine();
                        while (linha!=null){
                            ta.setText(linha);
                            linha = br.readLine();
                        }

                    }catch (Exception exception){
                        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele está lendo todo o arquivo sim. O problema é que você sobrescreve o que já foi lido e só usa a última linha lida:

```
String linha = br.readLine();
while (linha!=null){
    ta.setText(linha); // mudo o texto para a última linha lida
    linha = br.readLine(); // lê outra linha
}
```

Ou seja, você muda o texto do `JTextArea`, depois lê outra linha, muda o texto para esta linha, lê outra, muda o texto para essa outra, lê outra, etc. No final ele terá o valor da última linha.

Se a ideia é ter todo o conteúdo do arquivo no *textarea*, então primeiro você lê tudo e no final você muda o texto:

```
String linha = br.readLine();
while (linha != null) {
    linha += br.readLine();
}
ta.setText(linha);
```

Se bem que, para fazer concatenação de strings em um *loop*, [o mais indicado é usar um `StringBuilder`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String linha;
while ((linha = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(linha);
}
ta.setText(sb.toString());
```

O detalhe é que o `readLine` não traz as quebras de linha do arquivo. Se quiser incluí-las, coloque `sb.append(linha).append("\n")` dentro do `while`.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda, deu certo.