# Eliminar letras duplicadas consecutivas de strings

Tags: java, string, java-8

Como faço para percorrer um array de strings e eliminar as letras consecutivas repetidas?

Com entrada de:
`String[] x = {"lleonardo", "joaoo"}`

Saída:
`String[] x = {"leonardo", "joao"}`

Criei a função abaixo, mas quanto mais tentei buscar soluções, mas eu me compliquei, e agora estou "travado" e não consigo chegar ao resultado esperado.

```
    static String[] Palavras(String array[]){
        
        String[] resultado = new String[array.length];
        String y = "";
        
        for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
            String x = array[i];
            
            for(int j=0; j<=x.length(); j++) {
                
                if(x.charAt(j) != x.charAt(j+1)) {
                    System.out.println(x.charAt(j));
                    y += x.charAt(j);
                }
                
            }
        
        }
        
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Estou no começo, então se alguem conseguir me dar um norte, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os índices de uma string começam em zero, então eles vão de zero a `length - 1`. Por isso está errado fazer `j<=x.length()`, pois assim você está pegando um índice a mais no final e [dará erro ao tentar acessar uma posição inexistente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/112052). O certo é usar `<` em vez de `<=`.

Quanto ao algoritmo, basta guardar o caractere anterior, e você só adiciona o caractere atual na nova string se ele for diferente do anterior. Assim:

```
String[] array = {"lleonardo", "joaoo"};
String[] result = new String[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    String atual = array[i];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char anterior = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < atual.length(); j++) {
        char c = atual.charAt(j);
        if (c != anterior) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
        anterior = c;
    }
    result[i] = sb.toString();
}
```

Para criar a nova string usei um `StringBuilder`, que para várias concatenações seguidas em um loop, [é mais eficiente do que concatenar strings diretamente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052).

No final, o array `result` terá as strings sem os caracteres consecutivos repetidos.

---

Mas esta solução tem limites. Claro que se você só tiver strings contendo textos em português, provavelmente não terá problemas. Mas se tiver algo assim:

```
// sim, um emoji direto no código
String[] array = { "" };
```

Aí não funciona mais. A explicação "curta" é que internamente o Java guarda as strings em UTF-16 (segundo a [própria documentação cita](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html): "*A `String` represents a string in the UTF-16 format*"), e alguns caracteres acabam ocupando 2 `char`'s (imprima `"".length()`, e veja que o resultado é `4` - cada emoji precisa de 2 `char`'s para ser armazenado, e `length` retorna o tamanho do array de `char` usado internamente). A explicação longa para entender todos esses detalhes está [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052).

Enfim, se quiser eliminar os caracteres repetidos para este caso, aí temos que iterar pelos code points da string:

```
String[] array = { "aaxybb" };
String[] result = new String[array.length];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    String atual = array[i];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int anterior = -1, cp;
    for (int j = 0; j < atual.length(); j += Character.charCount(cp)) {
        cp = atual.codePointAt(j);
        if (cp != anterior) {
            sb.appendCodePoint(cp);
        }
        anterior = cp;
    }
    result[i] = sb.toString();
}
```

Ainda vai falhar se a string tiver [*grapheme clusters*](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/) ou acentos [normalizados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406545/112052) em NFD, mas se quiser se aprofundar nestes casos, sugiro ler [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/345946/112052).

Answer (score 1):

Uma abordagem um pouco diferente seria remover os caracteres repetidos ao invés de ir concatenando os caracteres distintos.
Como a classe **String** não possui um método para remover um caractere, a forma de se conseguir isso é usando o método substring ou convertendo a String para um **StringBuilder**, removendo o caractere repetido e fazendo a conversão de volta para **String**:

```
static String[] Palavras(String array[]){
    
    String[] resultado = new String[array.length];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        String palavra = array[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < palavra.length() - 1; j++) {
            while ((j+1) < palavra.length() 
                    && palavra.charAt(j) == palavra.charAt(j+1)) {
                palavra = new StringBuilder(palavra).deleteCharAt(j).toString();
            }
        }
        resultado[i] = palavra;
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Se você não tiver nenhum impedimento para utilizar expressões regulares, eu sugeriria essa solução mais enxuta:

```
static String[] Palavras2(String array[]){
    Pattern padrao = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z])\\1+");
    String[] result = new String[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        String atual = padrao.matcher(array[i]).replaceAll("$1");
        result[i] = atual;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Outra opção é usar `Pattern.compile("(.)\\1+")`, assim já pega uma ou mais ocorrências do caractere repetido (em vez de apenas uma), e na substituição fazer `replaceAll("$1")` - isso também evita o uso do *lookahead*, o que deixa a regex um pouco mais eficiente (não que regex seja a coisa mais eficiente do mundo, mas enfim, compare a quantidade de *steps* [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/mIK9NI/1/) e [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/bxlNgy/1/))

Comment: Boa sugestão @hkotsubo ... Melhorei a regex.