# Separar String em Caractere em Java

Tags: java

Gente, estou tentando separar uma string em caracteres...por exemplo, se eu digitar
"corrida" quero que saia "c o r r i d a", mas não estou conseguindo, onde estou errando?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class mensagem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            String mensagem;
            mensagem = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite sua mensagem a ser separada:");
            
            String vetor[] = {mensagem};
            
            for(int i = 0; i<=vetor.length-1; i++) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mensagem divida por caractere: " 
            + vetor[i]);
                
            }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Não esqueça de aceitar alguma das respostas caso tenham lhe atendido

Answer (score 2):

Poderia tentar iterar com uma instância da classe [`string`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). E iterar os caracteres desta String com o método [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)).

Segue um exemplo:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String vetor = "corrida";
        char c;
        for(int i = 0; i<=vetor.length()-1; i++) {
            c = vetor.charAt(i);
            System.out.println(c);
            
        }
}
```

Para tentar resolver o seu problema específico você poderia montar a mensagem que deseja exibir no optionPane, utilizando uma variável auxiliar.

Em meu exemplo eu mudei o tipo de [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) para [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) por questões de eficiência. Ao usar a classe StringBuilder devemos interagir com os métodos expostos pela classe StringBuilder, neste caso para fazer a concatenação basta utilizar o método `append()`.

Exemplo:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        final String separador = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        String vetor = "corrida";
        char c;
        StringBuilder tmpmsg = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i<=vetor.length()-1; i++) {
            c = vetor.charAt(i);
            //tmpmsg.append(c).append(separador); #para utilizar quebra de linha
            tmpmsg.append(c).append(' '); // #para utilizar espaços
            
        }
        System.out.println(tmpmsg);
        // agora só precisa criar 1 instância do jOptionPane (não é necessário fazer um for)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mensagem divida por caractere: " + tmpmsg);
}
```

Neste exemplo estou utilizando o método [`System.getProperties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) que é uma função helper para facilitar o acesso à uma propriedade do sistema operacional onde a JVM está executando. Neste caso estou querendo obter a propriedade separador de linha (`line.separator`). Para uma lista completa de quais propriedades podem ser acessadas basta acessar a [`documentação do método getProperties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()).

Existem algumas coisas para melhorar neste código como por exemplo modularizar as ações.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, atualizado, não encontrei uma boa referência (em portugues) para explicar porque concatenar string é ineficiente, eu consigo entender a sua explicação, mas gostaria de algo mais didático, aqui no sopt também não encontrei um conteúdo que possua boas referências. Talvez não tenha procurado os termos corretos.

Comment: Só faltou isso mas é de menos `System.getProperty("line.separator");` ela quer espaços não novas linhas. O código está bem otimizado. Quando concatena strings a operação é O(n) pois string é imutável e ambiente cria uma nova string 
a cada concatenação, Já o append do StringBuilder é temcomplexidade de tempo constante O(1).

Comment: PS: Caso sejam muitos caracteres ainda dá para otimizar https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#%3Cinit%3E(int)

Comment: Sobre a eficiência de concatenar strings em um loop: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/71517/112052 cc @AugustoVasques - vale lembrar que a partir do Java 9 mudaram alguns detalhes: https://www.baeldung.com/java-string-concatenation-invoke-dynamic

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu to com sono, eu li só o começo, me desculpe. estava escrito bem grandão **Um novo StringBuilder será criado a cada iteração (com o valor inicial de str) e no fim de cada iteração, haverá concatenação com a String inicial (na verdade StringBuilder com valor inicial de str). Então, você devemos criar StringBuilder nós mesmos somente quando estivermos concatenando Strings em loops.**

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro divida sua `String` utilizando o método `split`:

```
String vetor[] = mensagem.split("");
```

O que acontece é que você está mostrando cada caracter separadamente, mostrando uma mensagem para cada. Se estiver usando uma versão a partir do Java 8, você pode substituir o `loop` por:

```
OptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Mensagem divida por caractere: " + String.join(" ", vetor));
```